# Actual type cannot be inferred for the method accepting Expression<Func>

Tags: c#, type-inference, expression

I'm writing a small library for parsing resultsets of stored procedures (basically, very specific kind of ORM).

I have class

```
class ParserSetting<T> // T - type corresponding to particular resultset
{
    ...
    public ParserSettings<TChild> IncludeList<TChild, TKey>(
        Expression<Func<T, TChild[]>> listProp,
        Func<T, TKey> foreignKey,
        Func<TChild, TKey> primaryKey,
        int resultSetIdx)
    { ... }
}
```

Here method `IncludeList` specifies that result set no. `resultSetIdx` should be parsed as if it consisted of `TChild` objects and assigned to property defined by `listProp` expression (as an array).

I'm using it as follows:

```
class Parent
{
   public int ParentId {get;set;}
   ...
   public Child[] Children{get;set;}
}

class Child
{
   public int ParentId {get;set;}
   ...
}
ParserSettings<Parent> parentSettings = ...;
parentSettings.IncludeList(p => p.Children, p=> p.ParentId, c => c.ParentId, 1);
```

This method works as a charm. So far, so good.

I want to support different types of collections in addition to arrays. So, I'm trying to add following method:

```
    public ParserSettings<TChild> IncludeList<TChild, TListChild, TKey>(
        Expression<Func<T, TListChild>> listProp,
        Func<T, TKey> foreignKey,
        Func<TChild, TKey> primaryKey,
        int resultSetIdx)
    where TListChild: ICollection<TChild>, new()
    { ... }
```

However, when I'm trying to use it as follows:

```
class Parent
{
   public int ParentId {get;set;}
   ...
   public List<Child> Children{get;set;}
}

class Child
{
   public int ParentId {get;set;}
   ...
}
ParserSettings<Parent> parentSettings = ...;
parentSettings.IncludeList(p => p.Children, p=> p.ParentId, c => c.ParentId, 1);
```

C# compiler issues error message `"The type arguments for method ParserSettings.IncludeList(...) cannot be inferred".

It works if I specify types explicitly:

```
parentSettings.IncludeList<Child, List<Child>, int>(
    p => p.Children, p=> p.ParentId, c => c.ParentId, 1);
```

but that's somewhat defeats the purpose making call too complex.

Is there a way to achieve type inference for this scenario?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, I want to create assign the property with new collection value during mapping. Something along the lines of:

`var childrenBuckets = childrenResultSet.ToLookup(primaryKey);
foreach(parent in parentResultSet){
    var value = childrenBuckets[foreignKey(parent)];
    setProperty(parent, new TList{ value } );
}`

It would be harder if I can't create value with `new`

Comment: passing `ICollection` as @devio mentions, would still be a work-around IMHO. I am interested in the 'theoritical' aspect of the question, I see nothing wrong in expecting the type reference to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that the capability of the C# compiler to infer types does not work "around corners".

In your case, you do not need any additional method, just rewrite `Child[]` as `ICollection<TChild>` and the signature will match arrays, lists, etc:

```
    public ParserSettings<TChild> IncludeList<TChild, TKey>(
        Expression<Func<T, ICollection<TChild>>> listProp,
        Func<T, TKey> foreignKey,
        Func<TChild, TKey> primaryKey,
        int resultSetIdx) {
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Interesting. Do you have any reference to such gotchas on type inference?

Comment: I want to create collection behind the scene during data parsing. This means that ideally I need either specific type (and `new()` constraint) or to use `Activator.CreateInstance` for each property (which I'd prefer to avoid).

Comment: pass an ICollection factory rather than implying a collection type